# Who started a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

I'm assuming that the author of the first message of a chat room transcript was the one who established a chat room.

If I'm wrong, how else can I find out who first established a chat room such as `Lounge<C++>`?

Answer (score 8):

You can follow these steps to find who created the room: (using [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) in my examples)

1. Go to the ["access" tab](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta?tab=access) of the room:

   > [image]
2. View the list of Owners:

   > [image]
3. Go to the "general" tab, and search for messages containing "owners":

   > [image]
4. Filter the results to get [only messages by Feeds system account](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=owners&user=-2&room=89):

   > [image]
5. Go over the results, and compare with the list of owners from step #2. The one user who was not added by anyone else, as can be seen in the search results, is the creator of the room. Looks like [Tyler Carter](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/131779/tyler-carter) created the Tavern.

Comment: Gee, you should've been a scientist.

Comment: @IͶΔ lol, thanks! Though, it's too bad this logic kind of fails in case of the specific room OP mentioned. Might still try something, but looks like the Feeds user started to report RO changes only few months after that Lounge was created. :(